# How can I force a user off a field?

Tags: c#, focus, datetimepicker

I have a windows application where I have a date that when it is changed there is a lot of other things going on or have to be confirmed. So my goal is to have a wizard popup when they select the date to walk the user through the process. I don't want them to be able to change the date on the main form at all. I'll update it through the wizard.

Currently I'm calling the wizard on `Enter` of the `DateTimePicker`. I'm open to changing that if there is a better option but they have to actually select the field not just hover over it. The problem I have is that when the wizard closes, the focus/cursor is still sitting in the date field where the user could potentially change the date. I know I can check the `KeyPress` or on `MouseDown` to relaunch the wizard, but what I would RATHER do is just move the cursor to another control.

I tried `NewControl.Focus()` and this appears to work, however there are 2 problems with it.

1. According to MSDN, I should not be trying to change the focus with an Enter event. If COULD cause the application or OS to stop responding.
2. When I cancel the wizard it Enters the control a second time triggering the popup and when it is cancelled a second time it leaves the calendar open or part of the date highlighted (depending on who the user entered the field).

I'm open to all suggestions for a better way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you make the date a read only field, then put a button next to it to pop up your wizard?

Comment: There are 2 reasons for that. 
1. The screen is already crowded with a lot of other items and there is not much room for additional buttons.
2. That is not what the users want and they are the bosses. :(